# Cannot upgrade Python to 3.6 from 3.4.5 using Miniconda. Encountered UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, conda

I'm currently trying to upgrade my Python to the latest version using Miniconda.

My current version is the following:
[Python Version Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCSsN.png)

I tried to update my conda version and then install another version of python 3.6 but failed due to an error - UnsatisfiableError. [conda python install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo3JF.png)

Please help me figure out why this is happening. I'm in need of the latest python version.

Comment: What do you understand from the error output? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: "Please help me figure out why this is happening." Do you see the last line of the error message, where it suggests doing something? Did you try doing the thing it suggests? What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The latest python version is 3.8.  For your problem python, 3.6 must be on your machine already. You can install Python 3.6 from the Python web site. After installing it you don't need to run the `conda install python` but you do need to create a virtual environment. You can do this with the following command: `conda create -n py36python=3.6`. Where py36 is any name you like that represents a virtual environment. Be sure to activate the virtual environment with `source activate py37`  Then you can run python 3.6

If you wish to run Python 3.8 just download the new Anaconda release.

Comment: Thank you sir. I uninstalled my conda and reinstalled the latest version of anaconda and changed my default python to the latest version python 3.8.